# Vue js, Props not define in some pages

Tags: vue.js

I am kinda new to vue js and I really need some advice from you to do this task.

In my vue-laravel application,
I have multiple pages, and a component.
i need to provide an prop to that component, So I can use it as an Id.
But that componet is already applied in multiple pages. So I have to add that prop to each and every vue pages , that component has added,
Do we have any way to send an id to the componet(as a prop or anything else) without having to declare it in other pages.
Ex:
***first.vue***

```
<component id='1' />
```

***secind.vue***
component should be able to define without id property as well

```
<component />
```

Comment: as you can see in my answer below, you have to define it in every component - I don't know any other solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you want to pass data from your parent.vue to your childs child.vue.

So to answer your question: **you have to declare your props in every component below your parent**

If you send e.g. your `index` from parent to child it look like this:

*parent.vue*

```
<child :indexParent="index"/>
```

in your child.vue you have to define your property in your script like this:

```
props: ["indexParent"]
```

than you can use this value in here - if you want to have it in your child from your child.vue you have to send it again to it's child like this:

*child.vue*

```
<childsChild :indexParent="indexParent"/>
```

and than you can define it again in your props.

Hopefully this answer helps you out!

Comment: Thank you. What i am expecting is , want to declare that property only in one page without declaring that property in every pages